# 1990 Nissan TRX headlights and Tail Lights

Tags: nissan

I recently purchased a 1990 TRX and I'm hating the headlights as they only have a single bulb.
Just wondering IF there are compatible headlights and tail lights from something like an S13 etc ...

I don't mind doing a little modding just really prefer a dual bulb headlight with TWIN high beams ie. 1st bulb: Low/High 2nd bulb: High/spottie